# How to fix an Unresponsive "Results size" option?

Tags: google-custom-search

On my self hosted google Custom Search (i.e. not google Hosted), I am trying to show only 5 results per page.

I tried all numbers from 1 to 20 in (CSE control panel > Search feature > Advance > Websearch Restricts > Results size). However, in all cases the results sohw as 10 results per page, for 10 pages, no matter what I do.

I also added the following [API 2.0 functions](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element) in the search div, all lead to the same results. 10 results per page for 10 pages:

```
​​<div class="gcse-search" webSearchResultSetSize="5"></div>
<div class="gcse-search" webSearchResultSetSize=5></div>
<div class="gcse-search" webSearchResultSetSize="small"></div>

<div class="gcse-search" resultSetSize="5"></div>
<div class="gcse-search" resultSetSize=5></div>
<div class="gcse-search" resultSetSize="small"></div>
```

How to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix the attributes with 'data-'.  For example

```
<div class="gcse-search" data-webSearchResultSetSize="5"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. this attribute is written in a different part than the parameters on the API page, so I missed it.